# Python SQLite avoid overcrowding by deleting the last item

Tags: python, sqlite

I use sqlite with python, when insert a new row I want to delete one of the end

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO ORDERS (ORD_ID, TYPE) VALUES (?, ?)", [ord_id, type_n]);
conn.commit()
```

> ID   ID_ORD      TYPE
>
> ---
>
> 3    136984714   0 **<--(-1)**
>
> 4    136982197   1
>
> 5    136983730   1
>
> 6    136984717   0 **<--(+1)**

How it could be done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ord_id` is always guaranteed to auto-increment you could do:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute('create table orders (ord_id, type);')
conn.execute('insert into orders (ord_id, type) values (?,?);',(3,136984714))
conn.execute('insert into orders (ord_id, type) values (?,?);',(4,136982197))
conn.execute('insert into orders (ord_id, type) values (?,?);',(5,136983730))
conn.execute('insert into orders (ord_id, type) values (?,?);',(6,136984717))
conn.execute('delete from orders where ord_id = (select min(ord_id) from orders);')
>>> conn.execute('select * from orders').fetchall()
[(4, 136982197), (5, 136983730), (6, 136984717)]
```

As is mentioned in the comments you could alternately implement this as a trigger:

```
conn.execute('''CREATE TRIGGER delete_from_orders
                AFTER INSERT ON orders
                FOR EACH ROW
                BEGIN
                    DELETE FROM orders WHERE ord_id = 
                        (SELECT MIN(ORD_ID) FROM orders);
                END''')
```

Comment: ID is AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: You could also consider defining it as a SQL trigger

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @bsa. Added trigger definition.

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you!